# Sanitise text input for display on HTML page

Tags: c#, antixsslibrary, sanitization, client-side-attacks

Have built a chat program for our website.  A part of tHe program does allow a web page comment area for chatting about the page.

So there is a text input so text is entered and redisplayed on the page.
Obviously that is potentially risky.

So in order to make a text string input safe for redisplay on a web page, can I just disallow `<` and `>` chars and their encoded xml and hex equivalents?

Without script tags is there any other potential attack vector that can be embedded in a text string?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't actually need to disallow these characters, you can just escape them (e.g. `>` becomes `&gt`; and so on). This would safely convert all HTML into readable text. Remember it's not only script tags you can also do things like `<span onmouseOver="javascript here">`, you could also load images which could exploit browser weaknesses, you could add iframes that display malicious content and so on. So HTML-escaping the whole string is probably the safest option.

The OWASP project has some C# libraries which you could use for your purposes. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_AntiXSS_Library

Comment: If I disallow  script tags surely that covers images spans etc?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "disallow script tags"?

Comment: As in do not accept as input - client side and server- side

Comment: Sorry I was being unclear. What exactly counts as a script tag then, just `<script>` or any  HTML tag?

Comment: Sorry it’s me being completely unclear. I am referring to the greater than and less than symbols